# Не работает шорткод

Tags: php, wordpress

Создал простой шорткод в functions.php:

```
function footag_func( $atts ){
    return "test shortcode";
}
add_shortcode('footag', 'footag_func');
```

и если в админке на любой странице прописать так: `[footag]`, то при открытии этой страницы в браузере, выводит `[footag]`.
А если в шаблоне `page.php` прописать такой код:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[footag]"); ?>
```

то данный шорткод отрабатывает нормально, т.е. выводит `test shortcode`
Где-то видел решение в инете, в котором нужно прописать такой код:

```
<?php echo apply_filters('the_content',$post->post_content); ?>
```

только куда его нужно вставить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже на то, что тема самопальная. Контент поста в вашей теме выводится, скорее всего, через

```
echo $post->post_content;
```

а надо через функции WordPress

```
the_content(); // или
echo get_the_content();
```

Эти функции вызывают фильтры и шорткоды.

Можно и так, как написано в вопросе

```
echo apply_filters('the_content',$post->post_content);
```

Этот код надо вставить в то место темы, где производится вывод контента. Т.е. надо искать, где используется `echo $post->post_content;` и заменить на один из трех вариантов в ответе. Точнее сказать нельзя, не видя файлов темы.

Comment: ок, завтра отпишусь по этой задаче

Comment: вы правы, в теме не использовалась функция the_content(), было что-то типа такого: `echo $post->post_content;`